# Display labels on bar chart using Chart.js

Tags: chart.js

I am trying to display labels on top of bars using chart.js. My Y.-Axis has custom labels, like:  scaleLabel : "<%= value + '$'  %>"

So, my bar chart y.axis would be something like 1000$, 2000$ etc..
When I display lables on top of each bar, the values are displayed as 1000, 2000 etc..
Is there a way to display custom y-axis label on top of each bar?

I am looking something like, instead of 5000, how can i display "5000$" on top of each bar?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a single dataset set the **tooltipTemplate** in the options.

If you have several datasets set the **multiTooltipTemplate** in the options.

```js
var options = {
  scaleLabel : "<%= value + '$' %>",
  // String - Template string for single tooltips
  tooltipTemplate: "<%if (label){%><%=label %>: <%}%><%= value + '$' %>",
  // String - Template string for multiple tooltips
  multiTooltipTemplate: "<%= value + '$' %>",
};
```

See [an example here](http://jsfiddle.net/rdtome/xqdv1gzw/3/).

And the [documentation here](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#getting-started-global-chart-configuration).

Comment: I thought he was asking for the values to display on the bar chart "permanently" (not just on hover). That's what I need. I did upvote, BTW.